# SQL Server Query(Update) Recursiva Tabela de Saldos

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Eu tenho um banco de dados SQL Server com uma tabela chamada Saldos

Segue abaixo a tabela

| Id | Data | Entradas | Saidas | Saldo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3345312 | 07-08-2022 | 100 | 50 | 250 |
| 5435245 | 06-08-2022 | 50 | 50 | 200 |
| 4353451 | 05-08-2022 | 0 | 100 | 200 |
| 5762454 | 04-08-2022 | 20 | 100 | 300 |
| 7634523 | 03-08-2022 | 400 | 100 | 380 |
| 5623456 | 02-08-2022 | 100 | 20 | 80 |
| 4524354 | 01-08-2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

- Id = Identificador Único
- Data = Data da Movimentacao
- Entradas = Quantidade que entrou
- Saidas = Quantidade que saiu
- Saldo = Saldo da Data Anterior + Entradas - Saidas

O valor da coluna **Saldo** sempre deve ser igual a
(Saldo do dia Anterior + Entradas - Saidas)

Ou seja, se no dia 04-08-2022 a quantidade de entradas for alterada de 20 para 100, o saldo do dia 04-08-2022 em diante deve ser recalculado:

| Id | Data | Entradas | Saidas | Saldo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3345312 | 07-08-2022 | 100 | 50 | 330 |
| 5435245 | 06-08-2022 | 50 | 50 | 280 |
| 4353451 | 05-08-2022 | 0 | 100 | 280 |
| 5762454 | 04-08-2022 | 100 | 100 | 380 |

Eu tentei fazer uma query recursiva para atualizar esse saldo

A query não funcionou pois ele só atualiza o saldo do dia.
Exemplo: Se eu alterei as quantidades do dia 04/08/2022, ele só está atualizando o saldo desse dia, ignorando os dias posteriores.

Segue o que fiz até agora:

```
        DECLARE @DataMovimentacao DATE = '2022-09-04';

        DECLARE @SaldoAnterior DECIMAL(19,5) = (SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(Saldo, 0) 
                        Saldos 
                        WHERE DataMovimentacao < @DataMovimentacao
                        ORDER BY DataMovimentacao DESC);

        WITH Inventarios AS 
        (
            SELECT Id, DataMovimentacao, Entradas, Saidas, Saldo, 
                    LAG(Saldo) OVER (ORDER BY DataMovimentacao ) AS SaldoAnterior,
            FROM Saldos 
            WHERE DataMovimentacao >=  @DataMovimentacao)
        ),
        InventariosAtualizados AS
        (
            SELECT inv.*, 
            (COALESCE(SaldoAnterior, @SaldoAnterior) + QuantidadeEntradas - QuantidadeSaidas) AS SaldoReal
            FROM Inventarios inv
        )
        UPDATE Saldos SET Saldo = invAtu.SaldoReal
            FROM Saldos INNER JOIN InventariosAtualizados invAtu on Saldos.Id = invAtu.Id
            WHERE invAtu.Saldo <> invAtu.SaldoReal;
```

Comment: Acho que existem 2 recursos no SQL Server que facilitam essa atualização. Um deles é o uso da função Sum com as clausulas Over e Rows para obter a soma das entradas e saídas até a linha atual para conseguir calcular o saldo, e o outro é o uso de uma CTE atualizavel

Comment: Eu acabei conseguindo fazer o que eu queria usando um CTE somando dia a dia pelo ROW_NUMBER ordenado por Data
Postei meu resultado aqui como resposta da minha pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/563952/166775

Comment: Que bom que vc conseguiu obter o resultado desejado, mas da forma que sugeri não seria necessário utilizar a Row_Number, a CTE recursiva e o Join no Update, acredito que a desempenho seria um pouco melhor, só testando para confirmar

Comment: Vou ter que me aprofundar um pouco mais pra fazer isso. Eu li os artigos sobre as Window Functions que vc me mandou, li sobre o CTE, porém, não sou DBA. Sou desenvolvedor, eu não consegui pegar a solução na velocidade que a empresa necessitava.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente consegui resolver dessa forma

```
WITH Inventarios AS 
        (
                SELECT sld.Id, 
                        Data = Data, 
                        SaldoAnterior = CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,5), 0),
                        QuantidadeEntradas = QuantidadeEntradas, 
                        QuantidadeSaidas = QuantidadeSaidas,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Data) AS Linha
                FROM Saldos
                WHERE Data >= @DataMovimentacao
        ),
        RecursiveCTE AS (
            --Selecionei o primeiro saldo com data anterior a minha @DataMovimentacao
            SELECT TOP 1 
                Id, 
                Data = COALESCE(Data, DATEADD(DAY, -1, @DataMovimentacao)), 
                SaldoAnterior = CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,5), 0),
                QuantidadeEntradas = QuantidadeEntradas, QuantidadeSaidas = QuantidadeSaidas,
                Saldo = sld.Saldo
                Linha = CONVERT(BIGINT, 0)
                FROM Saldos
                WHERE CONVERT(DATE, Data) < @DataMovimentacao 
                ORDER BY Data DESC

            UNION ALL

            SELECT 
                inv.Id, inv.Data, SaldoAnterior = cte.Saldo,
                QuantidadeEntradas = inv.QuantidadeEntradas, QuantidadeSaidas = inv.QuantidadeSaidas,
                Saldo = CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,5), cte.Saldo + inv.QuantidadeEntradas - inv.QuantidadeSaidas), 
                inv.Linha
            FROM Inventarios inv
            JOIN RecursiveCTE cte on inv.Linha = cte.Linha + 1
        )
        UPDATE InventariosEstoquesSaldos SET Saldo = cte.Saldo, SaldoContabil = cte.SaldoContabil
            FROM InventariosEstoquesSaldos sld
            INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE cte ON cte.Id = sld.Id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiz com uma base de teste, segue abaixo o resultado.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    ID VARCHAR(10),
    DATA DATETIME,
    ENTRADAS INT,
    SAIDAS INT,
    SALDO INT
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
VALUES
('3345312','2022-07-08',100,50,250),
('5435245','2022-06-08',50,50,200),
('4353451','2022-05-08',0,100,200),
('5762454','2022-04-08',20,100,300),
('7634523','2022-03-08',400,100,380),
('5623456','2022-02-08',100,20,80),
('4524354','2022-01-08',0,0,0)*/

--DROP TABLE #TEMP
--DELETE FROM #TEMP
--DROP TABLE #TEMP2


SELECT * FROM #TEMP
ORDER BY DATA


DECLARE 
@D AS DATETIME,
@SD_INI AS INT,
@D_ANT AS DATETIME,
@CONT_INI AS INT,
@CONT_FIM AS INT

SET @CONT_INI = 0
SET @D = '04-08-2022'
SET @CONT_FIM = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP WHERE DATA >= @D)
SET @SD_INI = (
    SELECT SALDO FROM #TEMP WHERE DATA = @D - 1)
SET @D_ANT = (
    SELECT DATA FROM #TEMP WHERE DATA = @D -1)

/*
UPDATE #TEMP 
SET ENTRADAS = 150
WHERE DATA = @D*/

-- UPDATE COM LOOP
WHILE @CONT_INI <= @CONT_FIM
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #TEMP
        SET SALDO = @SD_INI + ENTRADAS - SAIDAS 
        WHERE DATA = @D + @CONT_INI;
    SET @CONT_INI = @CONT_INI + 1
    SET @SD_INI = (
        SELECT SALDO FROM #TEMP WHERE DATA = @D_ANT +1)
    SET @D_ANT = @D_ANT + 1
    END;


SELECT * FROM #TEMP
ORDER BY DATA
```

Comment: Funcionou legal sua abordagem, só que nela eu tenho que fazer vários updates dentro de um loop WHILE. Usando recursividade, dá pra fazer tudo num único update.